# Camera pics not appearing in Gallery app

Tags: android

When I take pictures using android.hardware.camera and I save them to the following location /sdcard/dcim/camera/ they don't appear when I launch the gallery. Is there a process for getting them to show up in the gallery that I missed?

I can see my images using a file explorer and know they have been saved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run `MediaScanner` on the type of media that you have saved to make your changes(SDcard writes) transparent throughout the system.
MediaScanner is bundled with devTools package so you can either run it manually or you can also do it via Java code(right after the write to SDcard op). Google "MediaScanner" you will find plenty of examples.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right direction, I was able to use this   MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(_context.getContentResolver(), FullFileName.getAbsolutePath(), FileName, FileName);